# skstorereviewcontroller is not showing on live app

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

It shows the rating prompt in development mode. However, it's not working on live app. I know it can show up to 3 times a year for an app on a device. Is there any logic or policies provided by Apple that tell us for sure whether the rating prompt will show or not given the conditions?

Note: The prompt shown once on the live app from my device yesterday. Now I have to demo it to my employer. I have uninstalled the app, changed apple id. Nothing is working to show the prompt again.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an excerpt from [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skstorereviewcontroller/2851536-requestreview) for `requestReview()`

> Although you should call this method when it makes sense in the user
>   experience flow of your app, **the actual display of a rating/review
>   request view is governed by App Store policy.**

It also states that

> When you call this method while your app is still in development mode,
>   a rating/review request view is always displayed so that you can test
>   the user interface and experience. **However, this method has no effect
>   when you call it in an app that you distribute using TestFlight.**

For demo purposes, I would suggest to use development version